# Javascript: onmouseover function for description box on website

Tags: javascript, html, web, onmouseover, onmouseout

I'm a complete amateur when it comes to Computer Science (potentially looking at studying at uni) but decided a few days ago to build a website to post science articles, aimed at students to grow their interest in science. The idea is that when you are on the catalogue page of all the articles I have written, you can hover over the title to read a description of what it's about. Whilst this descripton box idea isn't absolutely necessary, it is frustrating as I had it working yesterday with only one box, but now I have added another and attempted to properly name the writing it has broken! I know the code is rough, but if you could put aside any disparaging comments that would be great!

HTML

```
<p><a onmouseover="showbox('description')" onmouseout="hidebox('description')" 
href="Telomeres.html"> Title 1 </a></p>
<div id="description"><p>Description of title 1</p></div>


<p><a onmouseover="showbox('description2')" onmouseout="hidebox('description2')" 
href="index.html"> Title 2 </a></p>
<div id="description2"><p>Description of title 2</p></div>
```

Javascript

```
    function showbox('description'){
document.getElementById('description').style.display = 'block';
}
function hidebox('description')
{
document.getElementById('description').style.display = 'none';
}




     function showbox('description2'){
document.getElementById('description2').style.display = 'block';
}
function hidebox('description2')
{
document.getElementById('description2').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: You seem to be missing the point of arguments, for example in the function definition `showbox('description')` try using `showbox(id)` and call it using the id 'description', this will assign `id` to the value `'description'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one function for showing the box since you are passing the id into it. The thing in the parenthesis of the function is the name of the argument that is being passed in. Inside that function you can use that variable. So in your case, you would do this:

```
function showbox(nodeId){
    document.getElementById(nodeId).style.display = 'block';
}

function hidebox(nodeId)
{
    document.getElementById(nodeId).style.display = 'none';
}
```

For more info on javascript functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions

Comment: I simplified it down using only one title and one description box, I then deleted my javascript code and replaced it with yours. I tried it with "nodeId", "description", and " 'description' " to no avail unfortunately.

Comment: See this fiddle using my code: https://jsfiddle.net/tevdm1jh/2/ It is working as expected. The descriptions are visible initially so I just put in some CSS to hide them to begin with since I don't know what your CSS looks like.

Comment: #description {
display: none;
    padding:0px;
margin:0px;
border:2px solid gray;
z-index:1;
position:relative;
background-color:#fff;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 25px;
}

Comment: That css is setting the style for only the element whose ID is description. You should change that to use a class as I did in my fiddle (updated with your CSS): https://jsfiddle.net/tevdm1jh/3/

Comment: I see it's working on the fiddle exactly how I want it to, but for some reason when i implement it into my site it fails? Could it be due to my CSS (above)

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing it. Can update the jsfiddle.net example with your complete HTML and CSS?

Comment: It absolutely works now, so simply in fact i have extended it to three and four without breaking it! With the risk of sounding overdramatic; you are my saviour! This problem dominated me for hours last night, and hours this morning, I can't thank you enough! Posting questions always scares me, so I only made this account out of desperation so am quite  a low level, is there some sort of Karma/Repuation system to thank you with?

Comment: lol... welcome to the world of computer programming. IMHO - asking questions should never be scary. We all were beginners once and shouldn't ever look down on those who are where we once were. Just marking this as the answer is enough.

Comment: I do enjoy the collaboration culture that seems to be common in computer science, it's almost a polar opposite to the maths world where it's all about yourself, and working to solutions alone, and people who ask questions are almost looked down upon. It's a nice experience, and again, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are function arguments has quotes which is wrong, Also there is no need to have two separate blocks for `description1` and `description2`

You code should be,

**HTML**

```
<p><a onmouseover="showbox('description')" onmouseout="hidebox('description')" 
href="Telomeres.html"> Title 1 </a></p>
<div id="description"><p>Description of title 1</p></div>


<p><a onmouseover="showbox('description2')" onmouseout="hidebox('description2')" 
href="index.html"> Title 2 </a></p>
<div id="description2"><p>Description of title 2</p></div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function showbox(description){
   document.getElementById(description).style.display = 'block';
}

function hidebox(description)
{
    document.getElementById(description).style.display = 'none';
}
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/mvvtLt8h/

Hope this helps!